# Only first post has content in loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

My Wordpress site has a problem:
In my blog-loop only the first post has content displayed; for the rest `the_content();` never seemed to be called (checked with "inspect element").
Any probs in my code?

php/html:

```
<section id="blogPosts" class="clearfix"> 
<?php $myposts = get_posts('');
    foreach($myposts as $post) :
        setup_postdata($post);
    ?>
    <div id="post-&lt;?php the_ID(); ?&gt;" class="post clearfix">
        <div class="postHeader clearfix">
            <a href="&lt;?php the_permalink();?&gt;"> 
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            </a> 
            <h4><?php the_date(); ?></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="postTags clearfix">
            <ul class="tagContainer clearfix">
        <?php the_tags( '<li><div class="tagInline">',
                        '</div></li><li><div class="tagInline">', 
                        '</div></li>'); ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="blogContent">
    <?php the_content();?>
        </div>
        <div class="editPost">
    <?php edit_post_link('<h4>Redigera detta inlägg', '', '</h4>'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => 'Pages: ', 'next_or_number' => 'number')); ?>
    <?php //comments_template(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</section>
```

Comment: `get_posts('')` looks suspect. Shouldn't it be an array of arguments?

Comment: Any idea of what that array should be?

Answer (score 0):

Check all other posts for having content in it..
Posts can be get by

```
<?php $posts_array = get_posts( $args ); ?>
```

Default Usage of args:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 5,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'category'         => '',
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'include'          => '',
    'exclude'          => '',
    'meta_key'         => '',
    'meta_value'       => '',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_mime_type'   => '',
    'post_parent'      => '',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true ); ?>
```

Access all post data

```
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
$allposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $allposts as $post ) :
  setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

This is the simple code to get all the posts. You can check the code by print the data ( print_r($post); ) to check what you are getting in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the page that has been assigned to Posts under Wordpress Reading Settings, you can get rid of most of your code and simplify it:

`<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
       <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
       <?php the_content(); ?>
     <?php endwhile; endif; ?>`

Just put whatever information you want between the **while** statement and you'll be good. See the [Wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) if you want to get more specific.

Comment: `if (have_posts())` is redundant, since `while(have_posts())` alone will prevent the code inside from running if there are no posts.